# Proper Facebook Canvas Redirect

Tags: php, facebook, redirect

I'm having issues with redirecting to the website I want from the facebook canvas.

I am currently using a php solution to redirect the website using

```
header( 'Location: http://www.example.com' ) ;
```

While I feel this should solve the problem, instead it just loads the website into the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use javascript

```
<script>top.location.href="http://www.expample.com";</script>
```